# How to get a Confirmation event to trigger the right Dialogflow intent

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm working on a Dialogflow agent, coding in Javascript and hosting my code on Firebase functions. The agent is in Swedish if that's relevant, but I have translated the conversations to English here, in order to make it easier for you. I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong when using actions-on-google Confirmation helper.

This is the current state of my Confirmation intent:
When the user responds "yes" or any synonym thereof, the code works as expected, but "no" or similar instead trigger the fallback intent.

In Dialogflow, I have specified the correct input contexts (output contexts are handled in the webhook), as well as enabled webhook calls. I've added actions.intent.CONFIRMATION as an event in the confirmation intent (the intent that should be triggered by the user saying yes or no), and I have training phrases that are all synonyms of yes. If I remove the training phrases completely "yes" also triggers the fallback intent, which makes me think the confirmation event never triggers or is triggered incorrectly. If I add synonyms of no to the training phrases, a "no" from the user is interpreted as a yes.

The code in the webhook looks basically like this (only the relevant code is kept, because of NDAs, second intent is async because of API calls happening between user input and app response):

```
const setContext = (context, conv) => {
    conv.data.fallbackCount = 0;
    conv.contexts.set(context, 2);
};
const clearContext = (context, conv) => {
    conv.data.fallbackCount = 0;
    conv.contexts.set(context, 0);
};

app.intent(intents.correct, (conv) => {
    clearContext(contexts.what_help, conv);
    setContext(contexts.results_confirm, conv);
    conv.ask(new Confirmation("can you confirm?"));
});

app.intent(intents.results_confirm, async (conv, params, confirmation) => {
    clearContext(contexts.results_confirm, conv);
    if (confirmation) {
        //API-call
        setContext(contexts.dividend_confirm, conv);
        conv.ask(/*Dialog built by the API-call*/);
    } else {
        setContext(contexts.what_help, conv);
        conv.ask("ok, can I help with something else?");
    }
});
```

When the user responds "yes", the value of confirmation in the second intent is "yes", if the user responds "no", the intent is never triggered and the user is sent to the fallback intent.

I would be most grateful if anyone could help me get on the right track, currently, I'm stuck and none of the threads I find when searching have the same problem as I do.

---

Edit: I have currently solved the issue by adding separate "yes" and "no" intents and directing the user to them using contexts. It seems like there should be a way to avoid that sort of thing, but if anyone have the same problem as I have that is the only solution I've found so far.
I'm still very interested in more information about Confirmation events, if anyone can explain what I did wrong in my original solution, which is why I write this as an edit instead of an answer.

Comment: Do you experience the same behavior with "no" synonyms?

Comment: If I change the training phrases to "no"-synonyms, saying yes is not understood by Dialogflow, and saying no executes the code within the "if (confirmation){}"-block, and not the code within else{}.